# Java digital signature - java.security.ProviderException

Tags: java, random, digital-signature

I'm trying to make a digital signature of a file for which I'm using [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) from oracle.

It all works perfectly fine on my local machine, but as I try to run it on a web server with no mouse, keyboard etc. I manage to sign only one file and every another try causes a following exception to occur:

```
java.security.ProviderException: nextBytes() failed
```

This happens exactly when executing the sign function:

```
byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();
```

From what I've learned so far this might be caused by draining the entropy pool which is needed to generate random sequences. On a server with no input devices it isn't being filled fast enough. If this in fact is the case, one solution might be to change the source of random seed from dev/random to dev/urandom, but it's been told that it's not good for security reasons.

So the questions is: Is this really the cause of my problem? If so, what's the way of forcing Java to use dev/urandom? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Edit: As someone mentioned here, but has deleted his answer before I could respond, adding following code solved the problem:

```
if (System.getProperty("java.security.egd") == null) {
   System.setProperty("java.security.egd", "file:///dev/urandom");
}
```

It might not be the best solution but it's enough to sign and verify files.

Comment: A syntax sugar: `System.getProperty("java.security.egd", "file:///dev/urandom");`is the same of your if.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the way I read the JavaDoc, System.getProperty(String, String) doesn't have a side-effect of setting the property if it's not already set.  The second argument is only used as the return value if the property is not already set.